# Monitorig ZFS io with Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zfs, zabbix, io

I need to monitor per-zpool IO stats (number of reads, number of writes, size of reads, size of writes) with Zabbix. Is there a script for that?

kstat provides only agregate data (all zpools summed together) -- unix:0:vopstats_zfs:nread, unix:0:vopstats_zfs:nwrite, unix:0:vopstats_zfs:read_bytes, unix:0:vopstats_zfs:write_bytes.

zpool iostat does not have a switch to turn the "human-readable" values (K, M suffixes) into absolute values.

zpool iostat uses a ioctl to get the data from kernel. That looks like a "not-really-supported" interface to me.

Right now the best way seems to be to write a "translator" for the "zpool iostat" output, but I hope there's a better way and it has been done already.

Comment: Operating system you're using is???

Comment: Solaris 10, update 9 on x86-64.

Answer (score -3):

OK. In the end, I wrote a "translator" from the human-readable output of "zpool iostat" into absolute numbers.

If anyone wants it, contact me.

Comment: Consider yourself contacted.  Please post your solution for the sake of future google searches.

Comment: Juraj, I am unable to find any other way how to contact you. Can you share your "translator" for the ZFS IO zabbix? Thanks in advance.
Gabriel

Comment: Was anyone able to track down the translator? I am also looking for other templates for ZFS monitoring with Zabbix.

Comment: They are using a kind of translator here: https://github.com/bundgas/ZFS-iostat-to-Zabbix